# Scala's build.sbt not recognised by IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ide, sbt

I'm having an issue where my build.sbt file is not being picked up properly using IntelliJ (Ultimate 2020.2.3). I create a new Scala sbt project using the IntelliJ wizard (file > new > project > scala / sbt) and add a new dependancy to the buid.sbt file but when I try to import it into one of my class files, IntelliJ will not compile my project due to a dependancy issue.

The sbt tool window picks up the external dependancies but my project "external dependancies" doesn't contain the library at all, even after I refresh the project. Also, my build.sbt file has a bunch of errors in it like it's not being recognised properly by IntelliJ but I've installed the Scala plugin so I don't know what else I could do?

Here you can see that I've added the org.slf4j dependancy into my build.sbt; It's picked up by the sbt tool window (on the right) but not by my project (on the left)

[image]

When I hover over the `libraryDependencies` in the build.sbt file it doesn't seem to recognise the sbt syntax:

[image]

I cannot import the library into my class file and the project wont build:

[image]

I'm new to Scala and I'm simply trying to create a basic hello world project but I can't seem to get past this frustrating issue.

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: Yes, there was an error in the logs from my Gradle plugin. After I disabled/reenabled all of the unnecessary plugins things started to work! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to get past this issue. I'm not 100% sure what solved it in the end unfortunately but **disabling a bunch of plugins I wasn't using** seemed to fix the issue for me.

I suspect it may have been the Gradle plugin since I saw some errors in the idea.log file but after re-enabling the Gradle plugin to test everything is still working so not sure.

Comment: "Disabling and re-enabling of all the pugins" worked like a magic for me!! Nothing else was effective: not the intellij restars/ versions changes, update of sbt versions... only this plugin re-enable made the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You can try first to create an SBT project manually in some directory. `build.sbt` alone would be enough.

Then run `sbt` in that directory to see that SBT shell works properly. Try some commands like `sbt compile`, `sbt run` with some helloworld app. When you create helloworld app mind the directory structure where you put it, i.e.: `src/main/scala/HelloWorld.scala`.

If all that works go to IntelliJ and import/open project from there - select `build.sbt`.

When you create or import SBT project from IntelliJ it takes a while to bootstrap everything and download compiler, etc. Just leave it until it's done. Same goes for first time compilation when the compiler needs to be compiled :).

To setup a sample project you can issue these shell commands:

```
mkdir untitled
cd untitled/

echo 'name := "untitled"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.26",
)
' > build.sbt

mkdir -p src/main/scala/

echo 'object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
' > src/main/scala/HelloWorld.scala

sbt run
```

If there are not issues with these steps then import `build.sbt` into IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did actually try this but I was still having the same issue. What solved it for me was disabling all unnecessary plugins and re-enabling. That seemed to work

Comment: I actually had this problem (or very similar, but with a different intellij version) and doing what you suggested worked like a charm. Cheers.